# Basic SQL Statement (Where)

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have one table named **products** with the next tuples:

type
code
gestion
situation
subfamily

And I want to select *type, code, gestion, situation*, where *subfamily* are different values; *994, 948, 931*.

What I have done:

```
 SELECT type, code, gestion, situation
 FROM products
 WHERE subfamily = 994 AND subfamily = 948 AND subfamily = 931
```

How can I do it to not repeat *subfamily* all the time?
Thank you very much!

Comment: what do you mean by  `not repeat subfamily all the time`

Comment: This query should never return any rows - you cannot have more than 1 value for a field in the same row! Do you want to return rows which have any of these 3 values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `AND` here. Because `subfamily` will never have the values 994,948 and 931 at the same time. You should have used `OR` instead.

Or simply using `IN` (much better way for a list of values):

```
 SELECT type, code, gestion, situation
 FROM products
 WHERE subfamily IN (994,948,931)
```

Comment: I have to wait 2 minutes more to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the In statement:

```
 SELECT type, code, gestion, situation
 FROM products
 WHERE subfamily in(994,948,931)
```

Comment: No problem @DavidPradellCasellas we're always here to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the IN conditional operator which tests whether or not a value is "in" the list of values provided after the keyword IN.

```
SELECT type, code, gestion, situation
FROM products
WHERE subfamily IN (994, 948, 931)
```